# SMS - Which of the following url formats should I be using in messages to be recognized by most phones? - Twilio

Tags: twilio, sms, twilio-api

For an SMS message which of the following url formats should I be using and why?

- https://go.co/123
- http://go.co/123
- https://www.go.co/123
- http://www.go.co/123
- www.go.co/123
- go.co/123

I am using go.co url as example domain in my question, as my domain is a .co domain not a .com domain - in case it affects the answer recommended.

I like go.co/123 the best as it takes the least amount of characters. go.co/123 seems to display as a url on all smartphones I've tested with. However, is it not safe to assume that go.co/123 will always be hyperlinked, and that I should instead use http://www.go.co/123 as it is explicitly a hyperlink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL's are rendered by the end points, so it difficult to know all the permutations across devices and operating system versions of each device. The recommendation would be to stick with the standard URL formatting.

Also, be aware that carriers heavily filter SMS messages containing URLs, so it is best to avoid using URL's based on the filtering behaviors of the carriers in the countries you are sending to.

[How do SMS and MMS URL Link Previews Work on Mobile Devices?](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360013199334-How-do-SMS-and-MMS-URL-Link-Previews-Work-on-Mobile-Devices-)

Comment: Should I go with http "h ttp://go.co/123" since it is the older standard or "https h ttps://go.co/123"

Comment: I don't think that matters to be honest, everything is moving to https so I would personally use https.

Comment: I get your recommendation on using https, I'm hesistant to not go with go.co/123 as it is significantly less characters and all the go.co/123 links I've done do seem to be picked up on by the phones I've tested on iphone or android. If you have any final comment, would appreciate it.